# Swift 4 - UITextField DidBeginEditing

Tags: uibutton, uitextfield

I have four textfields (PISARadius, aliasingVelocity, AIVMax, and AIVTI) and two UIButtons (calcEROAButton and regurgVolumeButton).

I'm trying to enable the calcEROAButton only when PISARadius, aliasingVelocity, and AIVMax have numerical input and regurgVolumeButton when ALL four text fields have input.

I'm having some success with the following code, but when I clear one of the text fields, sometimes the buttons don't disable. Also, it seems that the buttons don't become enabled/disabled until the relevant textfields have been populated AND the user clicks elsewhere. Any clear remedy to this situation? Appreciate any input!

```
@IBOutlet weak var PISARadius: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var aliasingVelocity: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AIVMax: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AIVTI: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var EROAAnswer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var RegurgVolumeAnswer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calcEROAButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var regurgVolumeButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func calcEROA(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    EROAAnswer.text = String(Int(PISARadius.text!)! + Int(aliasingVelocity.text!)! + Int(AIVMax.text!)!)
}

@IBAction func calcRegurgVolume(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    RegurgVolumeAnswer.text = String(Int(PISARadius.text!)! + Int(aliasingVelocity.text!)! + Int(AIVMax.text!)! + Int(AIVTI.text!)!)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    calcEROAButton.isEnabled = false
    regurgVolumeButton.isEnabled = false
    PISARadius.delegate = self
    aliasingVelocity.delegate = self
    AIVMax.delegate = self
    AIVTI.delegate = self

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if ((PISARadius.text?.isEmpty == true) || (aliasingVelocity.text?.isEmpty == true) || (AIVMax.text?.isEmpty == true)){
        if(AIVMax.text?.isEmpty == true)
        {
            self.regurgVolumeButton.isEnabled = false
        }
        self.calcEROAButton.isEnabled = false

    }

    if ((PISARadius.text?.isEmpty == false) && (aliasingVelocity.text?.isEmpty == false) && (AIVMax.text?.isEmpty == false) && (AIVTI.text?.isEmpty == false)){
        self.regurgVolumeButton.isEnabled = true

    }
    else if ((PISARadius.text?.isEmpty == false) && (aliasingVelocity.text?.isEmpty == false) && (AIVMax.text?.isEmpty == false)){
        self.calcEROAButton.isEnabled = true

    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use custom method to detect textfield input, it may solve your problem.

```
  override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calcEROAButton.isEnabled = false
        regurgVolumeButton.isEnabled = false
        PISARadius.delegate = self
        aliasingVelocity.delegate = self
        AIVMax.delegate = self
        AIVTI.delegate = self

    // Add this selector to each of your textfield
    self.your_Textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .allEvents)

    }

    // Any of the textfield changes this method will trigger
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        // Add your logic 
    }
```